# Insert into dictionary with the same key name [python]

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to create a new dictionary from a list of dictionaries ;those dictionaries have repeated key names I need to append those keys with values to a new empty dictionary

```
items=[
         {
            'actual_batch_qty': 5,
            'actual_qty': 6,
            'allow_zero_valuation_rate': 4,
            'amount': 80.0,
            'base_amount': 80.0,
         },
         {
            'actual_batch_qty': 7,
            'actual_qty': 2,
            'allow_zero_valuation_rate': 5,
            'amount': 140,
            'base_amount':100,
         }
      ]
test={}
```

I trird but it it always takes the last dictionary values

```
for data in items:
   
    test['actual_batch_qty'] = data['actual_batch_qty']
    test['amount']=data['base_amount']
        
print(test)
```

outputs:

```
{'actual_batch_qty': 7, 'amount': 100}
```

Expected Output:

```
[{'actual_batch_qty': 5, 'amount': 80.0},{'actual_batch_qty': 7, 'amount': 100}]
```

Comment: the expected output is not valid Python

Comment: @gold_cy  Why not valid?

Comment: because what you’re describing is a set full of dictionaries, and that is not valid because dictionaries are not hashable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want a nested dict. In your case, you should use a list of dicts instead, but still by adding top level keys you can make a nested dict:

```
test={}

for i, data in enumerate(items):

    test[str(i)] = { 'actual_batch_qty': data['actual_batch_qty'], 'amount': data['base_amount'] }
    
print(test)
```

Output:

```
{'0': {'actual_batch_qty': 5, 'amount': 80.0}, '1': {'actual_batch_qty': 7, 'amount': 100}}
```

To loop through it:

```
for k,v in test.items():
    #stuff
    pass
```

Comment: so how to loop through this output?

Comment: yes if  continue with new_list=[] for k,v in test.items():
   new_list.append(v) will reach out the expected output Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD: Question was edited so answer below is irrelevant**

Use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict


items=[{'actual_batch_qty':5,
            'actual_qty': 6,
           'allow_zero_valuation_rate': 4,
             'amount': 80.0,
            'base_amount':80.0,
             },
             {'actual_batch_qty': 7,
               'actual_qty': 2,
               'allow_zero_valuation_rate': 5,
               'amount': 140,
                 'base_amount':100,
                }]

test = defaultdict(list)

for data in items:
    test['actual_batch_qty'].append(data['actual_batch_qty'])
    test['weigth'].append(data['total_weight'])

print(test)
```

Comment: this outputs: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'actual_batch_qty': [5, 7], 'amount': [80.0, 100]}) I need each key paired with its value even the key was repeated

Comment: dict in python is a key: value pair. How are you planning to retrieve a value from your expected output? If by index - you can create a list of dictionaries. If by key - you should create a key for each nested dictionary

Comment: I need to dynamically append the output to a list of dictionaries